# How to pass the values from the template as an argument to the function in views?

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-templates, django-views

I want the input entered by user in the template to pass it as arguments to the function which is imported to views.py ..this is the part of that template.

```
<form action="#" method="post">
     {% csrf_token %}
  Ratings: <input type="number" name="rate" step="0.1" min="1" max="5"><br>
  <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="mybtn">
</form>
```

This is the function I have used to import the function and pass the values as arguments.

```
def request_page(request):
users_id = request.user.id + 671
if (request.POST.get('mybtn')):
    updater.rate_movie(672, 6251, float(request.POST['rate']))
```

Comment: should it be (request.POST.get('rate')) even for this statement ?

Comment: what is the difference between request.POST and request.POST.post  ??

Comment: sorry i actually wanted to ask difference between request.POST and request.POST.get ??

Comment: If you read from the above link `request.POST` captures HTTP post parameters (`<form method="post">`) where `request.GET` captures HTTP get parameters (`<form method="get">`).

Comment: I have updated my function in view in the question please check it ..but still I am unable to call the function .

Comment: The `<form action='#'>` is wrong. What do expect to do when you hit the submit button? To submit the form to the `request_page` view?

Comment: I want to take the input from the user and pass it to a function ...yeah i want the inputs to be used in request_page view

Answer (score 1):

According to your comments above this should work:

```
<form method="post">{% csrf_token %}
    Ratings: <input type="number" name="rate" step="0.1" min="1" max="5"><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" name="mybtn">
</form>
```

Then in your `views.py`:

```
def request_page(request):
    users_id = request.user.id + 671
    if request.method == 'POST':
        updater.rate_movie(672, 6251, float(request.POST['rate']))
    return render(request, 'path/to/template.html')
```

Comment: I did the same thing as you mentioned above but still unable to call that function .

Comment: What do you mean "call that function". What function? `updater.rate_movie` ??

Comment: updater.py is the python file present along with the files like views.py,admin.py,model.py .... and rate_movie is the function I want to call in the in the updater.py .

Comment: OK. So do you import the `updater` file? Like, `import updater`? Do you get an error? Try to put a `print('Hello')` underneath the `if request.POST.get(...):` to see if it gets printed when you submit the form.

Comment: I have added a print('hello') as you have suggested but it is not getting printed .. is "from movie import updater" - is this the correct syntax from importing ..the file is present along with other files such as views.py,admin.py,models.py .

Comment: Try removing the `if request.POST.get('mybtn'):` and check if it gets printed now. Put it below the `if request.method == 'POST':`.

Comment: Tried but cannot see the hello in the terminal

Comment: Wait a minute there. Does the view actually renders this HTML page? I assumed that at the end of the `request_page` there is a `render(request, 'path/to/html/file.html')`. It is there, isn't it?

Comment: There is nothing to render after calling this function . I need not to render anything . I need to stay in the same page after clicking the submit button.

Comment: Updated my views file but still I am unable to call the function ...I tried calling it with all the values provided to check weather i am able to call function or so ..so what i did was instead of this updater.rate_movie(672, 6251, float(request.POST['rate']))  i have passed updater.rate_movie(672, 6251, 5) but I think i am able to call that function from views.py

Comment: Does your `request_page` view returns anything as it does in my answer? **Every view must return an Http Response**.

Comment: Actually this is for the ratings which will be provided by the user in the details page ..so i dont need anything other than taking inputs and passing it as an arguments for that function ..I have other function in views which return index page and details page .

Comment: Please delete most of your comments here. It's getting too big.